# Is there a R function to invert a likert scale values?

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, apply, tidy

I have a huge data frame in likert scale with values between 1 and 5. But i want change some numeric values inverting the scale, but manually would take much time. The question is: There a easier way to change the values?

I think a example work better, so this is the data frame that i have now. For each question there is a numeric representation of the answer.

`Q1 <- c(1,3,5,2,4)`

`Q2 <- c(5,3,1,2,4)`

`Q3 <- c(1,1,1,5,5)`

`my.df <- data.frame(Q1,Q2,Q3)`

`print(my.df)`

The data frame that i need have the opposite values that are saved in the database.

`Q1 <- c(5,3,1,4,2)`

`Q2 <- c(1,3,5,4,2)`

`Q3 <- c(5,5,5,1,1)`

`my.df2 <- data.frame(Q1,Q2,Q3)`

`print(my.df2)`

Maybe it's simple question, but i tried some functions of apply family, that return a list, all loops that i tried return a error, so i can't figure how make the change that i need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way:

```
6 - my.df
  Q1 Q2 Q3
1  5  1  5
2  3  3  5
3  1  5  5
4  4  4  1
5  2  2  1
```

Why this works: `my.df` contains only numeric data and arithmetic operations in `R` are vectorized. `6 - my.df` subtracts each value in `my.df` from `6`. Since `my.df` is a `data.frame`, so too is the output.

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful. You can create a `keys` data with the new values and reshape data in order to merge and add the new values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Keys
keys <- data.frame(value=1:5,new=5:1)
#Merge
new <- my.df %>%
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  left_join(keys) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=new) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     Q1    Q2    Q3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     5     1     5
2     3     3     5
3     1     5     5
4     4     4     1
5     2     2     1
```